# How to write this code in simple way?

Tags: c++

I developed a code in cpp which can read a text file and counts the words in it and stores the output in txt file.
like - 1 letter words *, 2 letter words* ,3 letter words_ etc.

I got the output but my code was not neat and my professor told me that you should have to write a code that everyone can understand. I tried to change it  but couldn't do it in better way. Please suggest me the way to do this task in short and simple way in Cpp.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void count_word();
void output_table(int&, int&, int&, int);

int main() {
    ifstream infile("input.txt");
    if (infile.fail()) {
        cout << "Input file not found" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    count_word();
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}

void count_word() {
    ifstream infile("input.txt");
    int l = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0; // l = letter count, x=1 letter word, y=2 letter        word, z=3+letter word;
    char c;                         // c = get command use from file;
    while (!infile.eof() || infile >> ws) {
        infile.get(c);
        if (c != ' ') // To remove the counter from counting whitespace  as characters
            l++;
        if (c == ' ' || infile.eof()) // Counter to implement the kind of words -> 1 word,2 word or 3 words
        {
            if (l == 1)
                x++;
            else if (l == 2)
                y++;
            else if (l >= 3)
                z++;
            if (infile.eof())
                l = l - 1;            // removing the extra space from the last word due to end of file
            output_table(x, y, z, l); // calling the output statements
            l = 0;                    // resetting the letter count to 0 for the next word
        }
    }
    infile.close();
}

void output_table(int& x, int& y, int& z, int l) {
    ofstream outfile("output.txt");
    outfile << "1 letter words  :" << x << endl;
    outfile << "2 letter words  :" << y << endl;
    outfile << "3+ letter words :" << z << endl;
    outfile << endl;
    cout << "Frequency of the word :\t" << l << endl;
    cout << "1 letter words :" << x << endl;
    cout << "2 letter words :" << y << endl;
    cout << "3 letter words :" << z << endl;
    cout << endl;
    outfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Try asking at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You could start with better names for your variables. If I read x, y and z, I assume that they are something like coordinates, not the amount words of a certain length. Better names would be words_one_letter or wordsOneLetter or something else that describes what the variable stores. Also, I'd went with if(!infile.eof()){ while(infile >> ws){ since a condition and another condition that has a side effect is somewhat much, but that might be personal preference (big variable names are preference too, but somewhat standard).

Comment: I agree with Aziuth that your variable naming is horrible. There is no reason to write 'as short as possible' code in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code Review:

---

You open the input file in `main` and open it again in your `count_word` function.  You may get errors from the operating system stating that the file is already open.

A good idea is to close a file before opening it again, or *pass the file pointer to the function*.  You could make the file pointer a global variable, but global variables are evil.

---

Variable names.  If you have to explain the variable's purpose in a comment, you have named it poorly.  Don't worry about the length of variable names because the length does not affect performance and is negligible in the build time.

---

The proper method to read until EOF is:

```
while ( infile >> ws)
```

BTW, the variable `ws` is not defined globally or in the `count_word` function.  The compiler should issue an error message for that.

---

Words can be input by using a `std::string` type variable:

```
std::string word;
//...
infile >> word; // Read a word.
```

Prefer not to use the `getc` method unless your application *must* read a single character at a time.

---

Use `std::string::length` to determine the number of characters in a word.

```
const unsigned word_length = word.length();
if (word_length == 1)
{
  ++words_of_length_1;
}
```

---

Pass by reference for large variables or if the function will modify the variable.  Prefer to pass by copy for small variables and constant reference for larger variables.

Your `output_table` function does not modify its variables, and the variables are small, so pass by copy:

```
void output_table(int x, int y, int z, int l) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way of doing it, by using **cstring** functions:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("file.txt");
ofstream fout("file2.txt");

void write(int length, char word[255])
{
  fout << length << " letter word: " << word << endl;
}

void read()
{
  char word[255];
  while(fin >> word)
  {
    write(strlen(word), word);
  }
}

int main()
{
  read();
  fin.close();
  fout.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but why you added char word[255];?